# -[UITextView setAttributedText:] stops working, when I use UITraitCollection variations

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview, traits, nsattributedstring

I have a UITextView set to display different attributed strings, depending on the device being used. But as soon as i am using traits, setText: doesn't work anymore.

I don't know where the information for the two texts are stored either.
When I look at the storyboard I see:

```
<textView>
    <attributedString key="attributedText">
        <fragment content="Large">
            <attributes>
                <font key="NSFont" metaFont="system" size="14"/>
                <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="natural" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural" tighteningFactorForTruncation="0.0"/>
            </attributes>
        </fragment>
    </attributedString>
    <variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact">
        <attributedString key="attributedText">
            <fragment content="Compact">
                <attributes>
                    <font key="NSFont" size="12" name=".AppleSystemUIFont"/>
                    <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="natural" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural" tighteningFactorForTruncation="0.0"/>
                </attributes>
            </fragment>
        </attributedString>
    </variation>
</textView>
```

But how do I access (and change) this variation at runtime ?

### How to reproduce:

I have the most simple setup. I let Xcode generate me a single view application. Then I place two `UITextViews` into the `Main.storyboard`. One is using a different text selected on `UITraitCollection` compact.

[image: Xcode Screeny]

Now I add two outlets to the `ViewController` and write some code in `viewDidLoad` to change the contents.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property( assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView   *textView;  // traits   
@property( assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView   *textView2; // no traits

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSParameterAssert( [self.textView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]);
   NSParameterAssert( [self.textView2 isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]);
   NSParameterAssert( self.textView != self.textView2);

  [self.textView setText:@"XXXX"];  // does not show up
  [self.textView2 setText:@"XXXX"]; // works as expected
```

}

Using `-setAttributedText:` doesn't make a difference.

[Download Xcode project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fld7bg8s7fbr8c3/TraitLocalization.zip?dl=0)

Comment: What do you mean by "One is using a different text selected on `UITraitCollection` compact.?" You check if `self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact` and then set the text?If so, you should probably show the code related to that as that's where the problem is.

Comment: In the screenshot it is shown how I have set two different texts to the upper UITextView in the storyboard in Xcode.

Comment: Here is the example project I used: [TraitLocalization.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fld7bg8s7fbr8c3/TraitLocalization.zip?dl=0), maybe it makes things clearer.

Comment: Why give it different text for different size classes if you are going to set the text in code?

Comment: It's a simplified example, just showing that `-setText:` doesn't work under these circumstances. In real life I would be setting two different attributed strings.

Comment: I've come to believe, this is just an Apple bug. Someone bolted on these variations and broke stuff in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem might be, that changing the text in viewDidLoad() is too early. I guess the changes are overwritten at some point later when the size classes / variations are applied.

I was able to kinda workaround this by changing the text in viewDidLayoutSubviews() instead of viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 0):

The method you should use should be a variation of this:

```
    self.textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                initWithString:@“xx”
                                attributes:@{}];
```

Comment: Thanks but as I wrote in the question: `Using -setAttributedText: doesn't make a difference.`